# android different langues for single textview

Tags: android, localization

How can I display multiple languages for single textview without changing system language?

[image]

here donor search is single textview with english and marathi languages at a time.

how to do this??

Comment: Use two `textView`s. One for English another for Marathi. Simple!

Comment: but how can i set marathi language for 2nd textview?

Comment: just set the text into the textView. the text can be in any language including mixing of any number of languages.

Comment: You can hardcode marathi in `android:text="Your marathi text"` or Add a String value (Which is recommended) in value folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a seperate xml file in the values folder like: values-in/string (for hindi)  then add your text in the xml file .You can direct show the text using android:text or textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.xxxx)); for next line use \n

References : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/

or

You can directly write text in xml and show int the textview

Comment: textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.xxxx)); this line picks up text from default system language , in my case its english. how to manually pickup text from any other lang

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do you can see the output

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A61jW.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghkNS.jpg)

```html
<string name="doner">Please search donor through code or name \n   (कोड किंवा नावाने दात्याला शोधा)</string>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/doner"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

doner">Please search donor through code or name \n   (कोड किंवा नावाने दात्याला शोधा)

Comment: <string name="doner">Please search donor through code or name \n   (कोड किंवा नावाने दात्याला शोधा)</string>

Comment: it works in my case...in this app primary lang is english and secondary is marathi...this solution may not work when app has primary lang is english and secondary lang is other than marathi

Comment: I have tested on 5  phones it is working fine . I have changed the primary language english  , marathi , hindi also. it may not work in emmulator because of limitations in emmulator

Comment: primary language is english by default and user will choose secondary language, it can be hindi or marathi or anythng else...

Answer (score 0):

Use /n in when you write text in textview like

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/deatils_news_img"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="This is just a text \n یہ صرف ایک متن ہے" 
            android:textColor="@color/colortitle" />
```